# create arrow below div with css using gmaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I want to create an arrow under the div like this:

https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/overlays.html

and i'm using the same code and i took the css from the source:

```
.overlay{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:60px;
  line-height:80px;
  opacity:0.8;
  background:#4477aa;
  border:solid 3px #336699;
  border-radius:4px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #333;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #666;
  padding:0 4px;
}

.overlay_arrow{
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-16px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position:absolute;
}
.overlay_arrow.above{
  bottom:-15px;
  border-left:16px solid transparent;
  border-right:16px solid transparent;
  border-top:16px solid #336699;
}
.overlay_arrow.below{
  top:-15px;
  border-left:16px solid transparent;
  border-right:16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:16px solid #336699;
}
```

So i noticed that i needed a div with the class overlay_arrow so i made some modifications to the gmaps code:

```
    map.drawOverlay({
                lat: destinations[i].Latitude,
                lng: destinations[i].Longitude,
                content: '<div class="overlay" id="' + destinations[i].Id + '">' + destinations[i].Name + '<div class="overlay_arrow"></div></div>'
            });
```

but still no arrow under the div.

What am i missing here?

[image]

Comment: Please, post a screenshot which is shown your problem because it works in Chrome ver 46.

Comment: I think the problem is z-index. Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Looks like you need to add either the above or below class to the overlay_arrow div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to add either the above or below class to the overlay_arrow div. At the moment the arrow styles are not actually being set.

For example:

```
   map.drawOverlay({
                lat: destinations[i].Latitude,
                lng: destinations[i].Longitude,
                content: '<div class="overlay" id="' + destinations[i].Id + '">' + destinations[i].Name + '<div class="overlay_arrow below"></div></div>'
            });
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!!